# How to check if all keys in json equal true

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I check if all the keys in a json object equal to true?
my object looks like this

```
    success = {
    "first_name": false,
    "middle_name": false,
    "last_name": false,
    "d_o_b": false,
    "sex": false,
    "email": false,
    "re_email": false,
    "password": false,
    "re_password": false
};
```

I proccess the object and every thing that turns out ok gets changed to true,
now at the end I want to check if all are true, how can I do this?
thank's :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Or a bit more functionally:

```
Object.keys(success).every(function(key) {
  return success[key];
});
```

Comment: +1 - you might note however that this code will fail in older browsers.

Comment: Never seen that one before. Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way is with a `for` loop. This will ensure it will work with older browsers that may not support iterators.

```
var all_true = true;
for (var s in success) {
    if (!success[s]) {
        all_true = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

The `break` is not strictly necessary but will short-circuit the loop if all you care about if that none are false.

Answer (score 2):

```
var everythingOK = true;

for (var i = 0; i < success.length; i++)
{
    if( ! success[i])
    {
         everythingOK = false;
         break;
    }
} 


if(everythingOK) 
    alert('Success!');
```

this should do ;)