# Object with boolean / “average” of boolean (better explanation)

Tags: angular, typescript

Having this object

```
        this.form= {
            info: {
                isactive: true
            },
            section1: {
                isComplete: true,
                subs: {
                    person: {
                        isComplete: true
                    },
                    workinfo: {
                        isComplete: true
                    }
                }
            },
            section2: {
                isComplete: false,
                subs: {
                    base: {
                        isComplete: true
                    },
                    address: {
                        isComplete: true
                    },
                    lr: {
                        isComplete: false
                    }
                }
            },
            ...
```

I would like to be able to set a section's isComplete property to true/false based on the subs isComplete.

If one of the subs[].isComplete is false then the section.isComplete will be false.

I have investigated the .reduce but without success.

I would like to have it work with any section with many needed subs
I am trying something like below (which does not work) for the moment...

```
obj = form.section1;
obj.isComplete = false;
for (const key of Object.keys(obj.subs)) {
    obj.isComplete = obj.isComplete && obj.subs[key].isComplete;
}
```

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Usually "does not work" isn't enough info for someone to help you; what, specifically, doesn't work about your code?  Is it that `isComplete` stays `false`?  That's because `false && anythingElse` is always `false`.  You should initialize `isComplete` to `true`.  You can also use `obj.isComplete = Object.values(obj.subs).every(v => v.isComplete)` if you want.  I'd make this an answer but I'm not sure if I understand your problem exactly without an easily testable [mcve].

Comment: The answer given in this post could be the solution you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752137/how-to-check-if-all-keys-in-json-equal-true/17752173

Comment: this.formSectionsAlt[parentSection].isComplete = Object.values(subSection).every(v => v.isComplete); made it; thank you jcalz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does not work

```
obj = form.section1;
obj.isComplete = false;
for (const key of Object.keys(obj.subs)) {
    obj.isComplete = obj.isComplete && obj.subs[key].isComplete;
}
```

Obviously this won't work, because `false && boolean` will always return in `false`. Please start with `true`.

```
obj = form.section1;
obj.isComplete = true;
for (const key of Object.keys(obj.subs)) {
    obj.isComplete = obj.isComplete && obj.subs[key].isComplete;
}
```

Comment: or just do `!!` and skip declaring it at all.  `!!obj.isComplete && obj.subs[key].isComplete`.